# Oracle 10.2.0.4 instance won't load after system reboot on Windows 2012 R2 server

Tags: windows-server, oracle-10g

I know it's prehistoric software but I have some legacy apps that require it.
When installing Oracle database 10.2.0.4 on a Windows 2012 R2 server 64 bit system everything works perfectly until I reboot the machine.
After the reboot I get a TNS error: permission denied when trying to start the oracle instance service.
During installation, the Oracle installer has no issue creating the database, the listener and starting everything.
If anyone faced this issue before any help would be appreciated.